# How to move multiple selected item from one listbox to another listbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have two listboxes named `listBox1` and `listBox2` with 4 items (strings) in both listboxes. I can select multiple items from both listboxes. I have also two buttons.

On clicking `button1`, I have to move multiple selected items from `listBox1` to `listBox2`. Similarly, on clicking `button2`, I have to move multiple selected items from `listBox2` to `listBox1`.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 5):

```
private void MoveListBoxItems(ListBox source, ListBox destination)
{        
    ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection sourceItems = source.SelectedItems;
    foreach (var item in sourceItems)
    {
        destination.Items.Add(item);
    }
    while (source.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        source.Items.Remove(source.SelectedItems[0]);
    }
}
```

Use:
On the click event of your move from 1 to 2 button:

```
MoveListBoxItems(listBox1, listBox2);
```

To move them back:

```
MoveListBoxItems(listBox2, listBox1);
```

Answer (score 2):

A [`ListBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx) has a `SelectedItems` property you can use to copy the items in the click event handler of the button. Like this:

```
foreach(var item in listBox1.SelectedItems)
{
    listBox2.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private void Move(ListControl source, ListControl destination)
{
       List<ListItem> remove = new List<ListItem>();
       foreach(var item in source.Items)
       {
            if(item.Selected == false) continue;
            destination.Items.Add(item);
            remove.Add(item);
       }
       foreach(var item in remove)
       {
            source.Items.Remove(item);
       }
}
```

then you can call it like this

```
Move(listbox1, listbox2);
//or
Move(listbox2, listbox1);
```

Comment: listcontrol doesnt have Items property. Change it to listbox

Answer (score 2):

According to this question [How to remove multiple selected items in ListBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483187/how-to-remove-multiple-selected-items-in-listbox)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    for(int x = listBox1.SelectedIndices.Count - 1; x>= 0; x--)
    { 
        int idx = listBox1.SelectedIndices[x];
        listBox2.Items.Add(listBox1.Items[idx]); 
        listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(idx);
    } 
}
```

You can do like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
       foreach (var item in listBox1.SelectedItems)
        {
            listBox2.Items.Add(item);
        }
        for (int s = 0; s < listBox1.Items.Count; s++)
        {
            for (int t = 0; t < listBox2.Items.Count; t++)
            {
                if (listBox1.Items[s].ToString().Equals(listBox2.Items[t].ToString()))
                {
                    listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(s);
                }
            }
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void move(ListBox source, ListBox destination) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= source.Items.Count-1; i++)
        {
           destination.Items.Add(source.Items[i]);
        }
    source.Items.Clear(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void Btn_Right_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        while(ListBox_Left.SelectedItems.Count!=0)
        {
            ListBox_Right.Items.Add(ListBox_Left.SelectedItem);
            ListBox_Left.Items.Remove(ListBox_Left.SelectedItem);
        }
    }

    private void Btn_Left_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (ListBox_Right.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
        {
            ListBox_Left.Items.Add(ListBox_Right.SelectedItem);
            ListBox_Right.Items.Remove(ListBox_Right.SelectedItem);
        }
    }
```