# How to remove multiple selected items in ListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

My windows form contains two listboxes. Listbox1 contains some items in it and listbox2 is empty.  When I press a button on the form, then multiple selected items from listbox1 should be removed from Listbox1 and copied to Listbox2.

I tried with foreach loop on listbox1.SelectedItems but it removes only 1 item from list.

Anyone has solution or code for this?

Comment: May we see your loop? You might have the solution, but with a minor bug :)

Comment: Maybe it helps to remove in reverse order.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could do all in a single loop. You should use a simple for and loop backwards on SelectedIndices:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    for(int x = listBox1.SelectedIndices.Count - 1; x>= 0; x--)
    { 
        int idx = listBox1.SelectedIndices[x];
        listBox2.Items.Add(listBox1.Items[idx]); 
        listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(idx);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you must store The values, you want to delete in other palce and then delete them from List,Here is sample code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ArrayList tmpArr = new ArrayList();
    foreach (object obj in listBox1.SelectedItems)
    {
        listBox2.Items.Add(obj);
        tmpArr.Add(obj);
    }
    foreach (object obj in tmpArr.ToArray())
    {
        listBox1.Items.Remove(obj);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I did this using using the CopyTo method to copy the items to an array the length of the count of selected items and then looped around that array removing each corresponding item from ListBox1.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     object[] itemsToRemove = new object[listBox1.SelectedItems.Count];
     listBox1.SelectedItems.CopyTo(itemsToRemove, 0);

     foreach (object item in itemsToRemove)
     {
         listBox1.Items.Remove(item);
         listBox2.Items.Add(item);
     }
 }
```

Comment: I think this is an elegant solution, because of the foreach instead of the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

For VS2005 I user something similar as I couldn't use .selectedIndices

```
  for (int i = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
                if (ListBox1.Items[i].Selected)
                {
                    ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.Items[i]);
                    ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.Items[i]);
                }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int x = listBox1.SelectedIndices.Count - 1; x >= 0; x--)
        {
            int var = listBox1.SelectedIndices[x];
            listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(var);

        }
```

Its Works.

Answer (score 0):

This is my method:

```
 List<String> arr = new List<string>();
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        arr.Add(txtItem.Text);
        lstItem.DataSource = arr.ToArray();
        txtItem.Focus();
    }
//When i delete
    private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (string item in lstItem.SelectedItems)
        {
            arr.Remove(item);
        }
        lstItem.DataSource = arr.ToArray();

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this code worked for me. The aim was to delete multiple rows of "items" with the press of the delete key. I have used a ListViewBox for the original input storage.

```
    private void visitorsOnsiteListLB_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.KeyData == Keys.Delete)
            {
               
                foreach (ListViewItem item in visitorsOnsiteListLB.SelectedItems)
                {
                    visitorsOnsiteListLB.Items.Remove(item);

                }
            }
         }
```

Comment: It should be copied to ListBox2, so your answer is incomplete.